# Setting the contents of a tag multiple times results in only the last value being displayed: why?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display multiple value in the same span tag along with a delay between different values.

Here is my HTML:

```
<span id="kontent"></span>
```

And here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
  }

  var json = [{
      "word": "zero",
      "delay": 3
    },
    {
      "word": "one",
      "delay": 3
    },
    {
      "word": "two",
      "delay": 3
    }
  ];

  $('#kontent').html(json[0].word);
  console.log(json[0].word);
  sleep(json[0].delay * 1000);

  $('#kontent').html(json[1].word);
  console.log(json[1].word);
  sleep(json[1].delay * 1000);

  $('#kontent').html(json[2].word);
  console.log(json[2].word);
  sleep(json[2].delay * 1000);

});
```

If I watch the console, I see this:

```
zero
one
two
```

each three seconds apart.

But the HTML display only 'two' after nine seconds.

So my question is this:

Why doesn't HTML show 'zero' and 'one' as well?

I have tried this with and without jquery and using different functions like `.html()` and `.text()` and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.html()` method from jquery which will replace the previous innerHTML in that tag.
You can use `.append()` instead. Like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
  }

  var json = [{
      "word": "zero",
      "delay": 3
    },
    {
      "word": "one",
      "delay": 3
    },
    {
      "word": "two",
      "delay": 3
    }
  ];

  $('#kontent').append(json[0].word);
  console.log(json[0].word);
  sleep(json[0].delay * 1000);

  $('#kontent').append(json[1].word);
  console.log(json[1].word);
  sleep(json[1].delay * 1000);

  $('#kontent').append(json[2].word);
  console.log(json[2].word);
  sleep(json[2].delay * 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by sabbir is correct insofar as appending the words to the kontent div, but looking at your code I felt it was unlikely to work as intended when it came to the timing. Indeed, when pasting your code into a snippet, I didn't get zero... on... two 3 seconds apart, but rather all three appeared at once after a long pause.

One problem with your code is that do / while blocks are blocking and prevent your code from doing other things while the loop is going on. You want to use things like `setTimeout` and `async/await`.

The latter is a real godsend once you get your head around it. It requires a bit of familiarity with Promises too. There are lots of resources on it, but here's the mozilla  docs on it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Anyway in this snippet you'll see it working as intended, and the sleep function is not blocking!

```js
$(document).ready(async function() {

  function sleep(milliseconds) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(true);
      }, milliseconds);
    });
  }

  var json = [{
      "word": "zero",
      "delay": 1
    },
    {
      "word": "one",
      "delay": 1
    },
    {
      "word": "two",
      "delay": 1
    }
  ];

  $('#kontent').append(json[0].word);
  console.log(json[0].word);
  await sleep(json[0].delay * 1000);

  $('#kontent').append(' ' + json[1].word);
  console.log(json[1].word);
  await sleep(json[1].delay * 1000);

  $('#kontent').append(' ' + json[2].word);
  console.log(json[2].word);
  await sleep(json[2].delay * 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="kontent"></span>
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you very much! And thanks for the link to 'async functions'.